# Pandas: How to read xlsx files from a folder matching only specific names

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a folder full of excel files and i have to read only 3 files from that folder and put them into individual dataframes.

```
File1: Asterix_New file_Jan2020.xlsx
File2: Asterix_Master file_Jan2020.xlsx
File3: Asterix_Mapping file_Jan2020.xlsx
```

I am aware of the below syntax which finds xlsx file from a folder but not sure how to relate it to specific keywords. In this case starting with "Asterix_"

```
files_xlsx = [f for f in files if f[-4:] == "xlsx"]
```

Also i am trying to put each of the excel file in a individual dataframe but not getting successful:

```
for i in files_xlsx:
    df[i] = pd.read_excel(files_xlsx[0])
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html). If all the files are in a folder:

```
from pathlib import Path
from fnmatch import fnmatch
folder = Path('name of folder')
```

Search for the files using glob. I will also suggest using [fnmatch](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.fnmatch) to include the files whose extensions are in capital letters.

[iterdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.iterdir) allows you to iterate through the files in the folder
[name](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.name) is a method in pathlib that gives you the name of the file in string format

 using the str lower method ensures that extensions such as XLSX, which is uppercase is captured

```
 excel_only_files = [xlsx for xlsx in folder.iterdir()
                     if fnmatch(xlsx.name.lower(),'asterix_*.xlsx')]
```

OR

```
#you'll have to test this, i did not put it though any tests
excel_only_files = list(folder.rglob('Asterix_*.[xlsx|XLSX]')
```

from there, you can run a list comprehension to read your files:

```
 dataframes = [pd.read_excel(f) for f in excel_only_files]
```

Comment: You can also use glob and rglob instead of the if statement

Comment: yea, rglob in particular, but the fnmatch allows you to capture filename extensions in uppercase. rglob is case sensitive.

Comment: but you could lower each element in the list comp right? `[xlsx.lower() for xlsx in ...rglob('*asterix*.xlsx*']`

Comment: you cant use lower on a file when using the pathlib. that's where the name method comes into play

Comment: @sammywemmy this puts in in just one dataframe. I want to put it in separate dataframes. Is it possible?

Comment: could you explain more what you mean by separate dataframes, as it is just a list and the dataframes have not been combined. so, dataframes will just be [df1,df2,df3,...]

Comment: @sammywemmy This is as expected. It works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use glob.glob to do your pattern matches

```
import glob

for i in glob.glob('Asterix_*.xlsx'):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

First generate a list of files you want to read in using `glob` (based on @cup's answer) and then append them to a list.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

my_df_list = [pd.read_excel(f) for f in glob.iglob('Asterix_*.xlsx')]
```

Depending on what you want to achieve, you can also use a `dict` to allow for key-value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the if statement you need to add another condition for files which also contain 'Asterix_':

```
files_xlsx = [f for f in files if f[-4:] == "xlsx" and "Asterix_" in f]
```

The `f[-4:] == "xlsx"` is to make sure the last 4 characters of the file name are xlsx and `"Asterix_" in f` makes sure that "Asterix_" exists anywhere in the file name.

To then read these using pandas try:

```
for file in excel_files:
    df = pd.read_excel(file)
    print(df)
```

That should print the result of the DataFrame read from the excel file

Answer (score 0):

If you have read in the file names, you can make sure that it starts with and ends with the desired strings by using this list comprehension:

```
files = ['filea.txt', 'fileb.xlsx', 'filec.xlsx', 'notme.txt']
files_xlsx = [f for f in files if f.startswith('file') and f.endswith('xlsx')]
files_xlsx # ['fileb.xlsx', 'filec.xlsx']
```

The list comprehension says, "Give me all the files that start with `file` AND end with `xlsx`.